# Am I leaving a security vulnerability in my CSP header by adding a meta tag to be compatible with Material UI?

Tags: material-ui, content-security-policy

I'm working on tightening security on a bunch of web applications. One of them has a React frontend with the Material UI library. This is important, as you will see.

First I created a standard CSP header and added sha256 hashes for all the style tags to the style-src section. This worked well enough, however as I'm sure you can already guess it was brittle because differences in style tags meant changing the hashes. In addition, Material UI generates most of its styles as dynamically-created style tags, so there were a LOT of hashes to add. Point is, this was not a scalable approach.

I have now changed gears to nonces. I added this meta line to my index.html:

```
<meta property="csp-nonce" content="**CSP_NONCE**" />
```

My nginx server will automatically generate a random nonce on each request and insert it into the content attribute. This is then used by Material UI to slap a nonce onto each of its style tags, thus allowing them to comply with my CSP.

My question is: does doing this make my CSP less secure? I understand the CSP is meant to protect against XSS attacks. If I'm putting a valid nonce in my HTML, does that mean the nonce could be stolen by an attacker and used to protect their attacking code?

As I write this, I am realizing that Material UI is coming from already-trusted script tags, vs a malicious inline script which wouldn't be able to execute anyway. So that's probably why it's secure. I'm relatively new to the world of CSPs, and while I feel I have a decent understanding of it, more knowledge is always great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of discussion of [this](https://csplite.com/csp258/) source. Is it safe to pass a 'nonce' in a meta tag? Can it be stolen and used by an attacker?

To answer the question from a practical point of view, we need to understand what we are actually defending against.
Third-party scripts can get to the page in a few ways:

1. web page classic XSS vulnerability
2. browser plugun
3. viruses on PC or home router
4. hacking hosting
5. injection by ISPs
6. DNS spoofing

The ways 2-5 imply that the attacker technically has access to nonce and can modify a CSP header, therefore those are out of question in matter of topic.
 In the way 6 attacker do not have any access to 'nonce' not on HTTP header, nor in HTML. So we exclude this matter from discussion.

It's remain only the analysis of stealing and usage 'nonce' through the classic XSS vulnerability.
Attacker can get actual 'nonce' using a script, but this script must be in advance allowed to execute - have valid 'nonce' or be from a trusted source BEFORE browser parse HTML of the page.
But in this scenario, the attacker is always 1 step behind.

After loading the page in the browser, the "secrecy" of 'hash-value' loses its meaning. *Knowledge the results of the race after its end does not allow to make the bet*.

In view of the above I do not see a reducing of security in transfer nonces via:

```
<meta property="csp-nonce" content="**CSP_NONCE**" />
```

Maybe I missed some kind of attack vector?

**UPDATED**
Yes, I have missed some kinds of attacks of stealing and reuse 'nonce', for example: reloading the page without trigger the request to server (reloading page from HTTP cache, AppCache, browser B/F cache).
Such tricks like:

```
victimFrame.src = "data:text/html,<script>history.back()</script>"
```

allow to steal 'nonce' value via CSSAR (CSS Attribute Reading) and reuse it.

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to educate myself much more on application safety. There are a number of topics like this that I more know "I should do this" vs "why I should do this", so I've been trying to fill in the "why". I appreciate the input, and am always open to links to good documentation on the topic.

Comment: As I discovered a couple days ago, using `<meta property="csp-nonce" content="this-is-a-nonce-123" />` is [requirement of Material UI](https://material-ui.com/ru/styles/advanced/#how-does-one-implement-csp) itself: *You must include this header regardless of whether or not SSR is used* (at the bottom of page)